# How to change wanted job position in my CV on stackoverflow.com/jobs?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

On page https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/cv/edit after pressing `Edit` button in first block, name, location, phone and others could be changed. But how to change job position?

Comment: Position is pulled from your Experience section.

Comment: This is the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Position is pulled from your Experience section. Edit last **Job Title**.

*[Mike McCaughan](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/215552/mike-mccaughan) gave answer to this question in comment. Thank you, Mike.*